# Continuity of functions of bounded variation

Tags: analysis, bounded-variation

I want to show the following statement.

> Let $f$ be of bounded variation on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $$V_f(x)=V(f; -\infty, x)$$ Prove that $f$ is continuous at $c$ if and only if $V_f$ is continuous at $c$. (Douglass, 5.25)

I can prove this fact for $V_f(x)=V(f; a, x)$, when the bounded variation is over the interval $[a, b]$. However, I am having a hard time for proving when one of the interval bound is negative infinity. Douglass defines the definition of these kinds of bounded variation as
$$V(f; -\infty, x)=\sup\{V(f; a, b) | [a, b] \subset (\infty, x]\}$$
So I have two supremum in my definition of $V_f(x)$. How can I prove this statement?

Comment: Since $V(f;a,b)  + V(f;b,c) = V(f;a,c)$ for $a<b<c$, you have for $x>a$ : $$V_f(x) = V_f(a) + V(f;a,x)$$

Comment: @SolubleFish Oh thanks, it was just from one of the properties. I can solve it from here now. Thanks for helping me out.